# Renaming single column of multi-index pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a multiindex. The columns look like:

Ex. Df:

```
      index date        Text        Text        Text        Text        Text
OtherText               OtherText1  OtherText1  OtherText1  OtherText1  OtherText1
Col                     Col1        Col2        Col3        Col4        Col5
        0   17-Jun-14   1           2           3           4           5
```

Code to create:

```
arrays = [['Date', 'Text', 'Text', 'Text', 'Text', 'Text'],
      ['', 'OtherText1', 'OtherText1', 'OtherText1', 'OtherText1', 'OtherText1'],
      ['', 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5']]
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(1,6), columns=arrays)
```

Column Names:

```
[('date', '', ''),
 ('text', 'somemoretext', 'Col1'),
 ('text', 'somemoretext', 'Col2'),
 ('text', 'somemoretext', 'Col3')...]
```

I'm looking to either rename, or swap the level of the first column. This did not produce an error, but also did not change the columns.

```
df.rename(columns={"('date', '', '')" : "('', '' 'date')"}, inplace=True)
```

How do you reorder and/or rename a specific column in a multiindex?

Desired Output:

```
      index             Text        Text        Text        Text        Text
OtherText               OtherText1  OtherText1  OtherText1  OtherText1  OtherText1
Col          date       Col1        Col2        Col3        Col4        Col5
        0   17-Jun-14   1           2           3           4           5
```

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html?highlight=swap%20level#pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel

Comment: @Jeff That works for the entire dataframe easily. How would you apply this to a single column? `df[('date', '', '')].swaplevel(0, 2)` did not work.

Comment: you should show how you constructed the frame, and what you are trying to do. that usage doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Jeff The dataframe is generated from a pivot table that has the index reset. I need to format the table in a specific way before outputting it to a csv, where it will go on to take a life of its own. I don't get to choose the level of where the 'date' text gets placed.

Comment: you should show it. ``df.head()``.

Comment: I'm not sure how showing the dataframe helps with changing the formatting... Are you saying I should show the dataframe in the question?

Comment: yes. your input frame, and what you desire as output. otherwise you won't get any responses and those that do will simply be guesses.

Comment: @DataSwede: the idea is that if you give something that can be copied and pasted, then it's very easy for someone to do so and play around for the minute or two it will take to confirm an idea about how to solve the problem.  Otherwise someone has to spend time coming up with a toy example, which often (from past experience) turns out to differ from the actual problem in some subtle way, which leads to frustration for all concerned.  As a result, many of the top answerers avoid questions without [SSCCEs](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I've added a couple line to create a sample df for convenience.

Comment: its looks like you want a multi-index on the index & the columns yes? e.g. is Date a column or do you want it as an index?

Comment: Edited the text- there was an extra 0. The code to create the df is how it actually looks. Date needs to be its own column. Only multiindex on the columns- not the index. The first column is simply the standard integer index that occurs after calling reset_index(). It won't be included in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this.

```
In [17]: df.set_index('Date').reset_index(col_level=2)
Out[17]: 
                   Text                                        
             OtherText1                                        
       Date        Col1      Col2      Col3      Col4      Col5
0 -1.468055   -1.528279 -1.230268  0.010953 -1.344443  0.650798
```

I am not sure why you are using multi-indexed columns in this way. HTH.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. The col_level=2 specifically. I think creating a IPython notebook and putting it online may make it more clear. The key is I don't get to choose how the output needs to be formatted- I just need to make it match it.